# Center component vertically and horizontally in 'Antd' library not working

Tags: css, reactjs, antd

I have a weird issue where I can't center a Row vertically in my screen.
The Card I have is perfectally centered horizontally but not vertically. How can I do that ?
I used the Row component which has `align='middle'` to align vertically but it isn't working

Here is my implementation:

```
<Row align='middle' justify='center'>
                <Col span={18}>
                    <Card>
                        {/* <img className='login-logo' src={logo} alt='logo' /> */}
                        <Text size='30px' type='BOLD'>
                            QIFF DASHBOARD
                        </Text>
                        <Form name='login' onFinish={formik.handleSubmit}>
                            <Form.Item>
                                <Input
                                    id='email'
                                    name='email'
                                    label='Email'
                                    placeholder='Email'
                                    type='email'
                                    autoComplete='new-email'
                                    onBlur={formik.handleBlur}
                                    onChange={formik.handleChange}
                                    value={formik.values.email}
                                />
                                {formik.errors.email ? <Text>{formik.errors.email}</Text> : null}
                            </Form.Item>
                            <Form.Item>
                                <Input
                                    id='password'
                                    name='password'
                                    placeholder='Password'
                                    type='password'
                                    autoComplete='new-password'
                                    onBlur={formik.handleBlur}
                                    onChange={formik.handleChange}
                                    value={formik.values.password}
                                />
                                {formik.errors.password ? <Text>{formik.errors.password}</Text> : null}
                            </Form.Item>
                            <div className='submit-button'>
                                <Button
                                    htmlType='submit'
                                    onClick={formik.handleSubmit}
                                    style={{ width: '100%', backgroundColor: '#f85940', color: 'white' }}
                                >
                                    Sign in
                                </Button>
                            </div>
                        </Form>
                    </Card>
                </Col>
            </Row>
```

Comment: @SiddharthVarangaonkar it didn't do anything unfortunately

Answer (score 1):

```
<Row align='middle' justify='center'></Row>
```

Presumably, the `Row` tag does not set the attribute `display:flex`

So `justify='center'` is invalid

The following solutions can be used：

1、Child element (Need to be centered vertically)

```
    position: relative;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    transform: translate(-50%,-50%);
```

2、 `<Row style="display:flex"></Row>`

Comment: Thank you this worked, I also had to add `height: 100vh` for it to work

Comment: Yes it needs a height